# Drawing an array of PictureBoxes in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to draw an array of PictureBoxes, for testing I use the same picture for each picturebox.

But instead of showing the picture, it shows the color blue.

I would show you a picture, but I dont have 10 reputation..

```
        Dim teren(120) As PictureBox
        Dim x_locatie As Integer = 1, y_locatie As Integer = 0
        For i = 0 To 10
        x_locatie = 210
        For j = 0 To 12
            teren(i * j) = New PictureBox()
            teren(i * j).Size = New Size(61, 61)
            teren(i * j).Name = "x" + i.ToString + "y" + j.ToString
            teren(i * j).Location = New Point(x_locatie, y_locatie)
            Dim locatie As String = folder + "\harta\test.png"
            teren(i * j).ImageLocation = locatie
            teren(i * j).Show()
        Next
        y_locatie += 61
    Next
```

I also tried another method , but same result.

```
Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender1 As Object, er As PaintEventArgs)
    If myImage IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim r As New Rectangle(x, y, xlatime, ylungime)
        er.Graphics.DrawImage(myImage, r)
    End If
End Sub

Sub deseneaza(ByVal poza As String, ByRef x_perm As Integer, ByRef y_perm As Integer, ByRef lungime As Integer, ByRef latime As Integer)
    myImage = Image.FromFile(poza)
    x = x_perm
    y = y_perm
    xlatime = latime
    ylungime = lungime
    Refresh()
End Sub

 'this part of code is in body of another function
 Dim x_locatie As Integer = 1, y_locatie As Integer = 0
        For i = 0 To 10
        x_locatie = 210
        For j = 0 To 12
            Dim locatie As String = folder + "\harta\test.png"
            deseneaza(locatie, x_locatie, y_locatie, 61, 61)
        Next
        y_locatie += 61
    Next
```

I saw in other threads that their problem solution was something like that `Dim teren() As PictureBox {teren1, teren2 , ... , teren n}` But the problem in my case is that I need 120 PictureBoxes, and I think that it must be a way to do this without writing 120 pictureboxes.

Comment: That seems a bit control heavy. You could use a `List(Of Rectangle)` and draw images to them. Much lower memory footprint.

Comment: @OneFineDay but i must write 120 of rectangles , right ?

Comment: As many as you require!

Comment: Could you explain what it is for? It looks like tiles to me.

Comment: @OneFineDay that array represents a map, so every time when the caracter moves i must draw it again.. And i dont think that a `List(Of Rectangle)` is the best ideea.

Comment: The System can draw rectangles with blazing speed. You could paint these to a surface and have that surface move based on the move buttons you have, then paint the character on top of that.

Comment: But at the beggining of the game, map will be empty, right ?

Comment: That depends on when you load the map.

Comment: Well, i want to have the map loaded at the beggin.. I mean, when i press the start button, the map must be loaded.

Comment: Since the drawing lives in the paint event you need a boolean to set to true so the paint event can check before drawing. Load the rectangles with the load event.

Comment: The problem with this post is that you don't have a simple problem to fix, you have a whole design problem to fix. It is very hard to answer these as they become quite involved. This is not the purpose of this site. I will give the simplest answer I can for what I think you need to do - since it seems the question is more about the design then how to implement it - which should be other questions for each issue you may need help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `GDI+` will be the way to go. I think you need a custom class that has a rectangle structure as a member with other properties that help you with further logic with the character intersecting with them. Paint should be done in the Paint event of the surface control you are using - `PictureBox` has the best rendering - IMO.

```
Public Class Tile
  Public Property Bounds As New Rectangle
  Public Property IsImpassable As Boolean
  'others you think of
End Class
```

Comment: I understand, thank you a lot, i think that i am going to use another programming language.

Comment: How will that help you?

Comment: How about a diff platform? [XNA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203894.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this...it will generate 16 picture box, size 20x20, in a row. I put it under "FormLoading" event.

```
        Dim Shapes(16) As PictureBox
        For i = 1 To 16
            Shapes(i) = New PictureBox
            With Shapes(i)
                .BackColor = SystemColors.Control 'Color.Green
                .BackgroundImage = New Bitmap(My.Resources.led_blk)
                .BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom
                .Size = New Size(20, 20)
                .Visible = True
                .Location = New Point( 23 * i, 50)
            End With
            Me.Controls.Add(Shapes(i))
      Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim iTop = 325
Dim pBox(48) As PictureBox
Dim pinColor = Color.SkyBlue
Dim leftStart = 50
For j = 0 To 3
    For i = 0 To 11
        pBox(i) = New PictureBox
        'pBox(i).Image = Image.FromFile("\NoTest.bmp")
        pBox(i).Visible = True
        pBox(i).BackColor = pinColor
        pBox(i).Top = iTop + (j * 40)


        pBox(i).Width = 20
        pBox(i).Height = 20
        pBox(i).Left = leftStart + (35 * i)
        If i > 9 Then
            pBox(i).Left = leftStart + (35 * i) + 15
            pBox(i).Width = 25
        End If

        pBox(i).BringToFront()
        pBox(i).SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        Controls.Add(pBox(i))
    Next
Next
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).